# Why does Tyrion give his companion this advice?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In [chapter 22 of ADWD](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_VI_(A_Dance_with_Dragons)), over a game of cyvasse:

> Tyrion suggests that Aegon head to Westeros instead of going east to meet Daenerys.

Why does Tyrion suggest this strategy?

Comment: Off the top of my head, Tyrion later says that he "took the bait," so the advise is probably self-serving in some way. My guess is because he knows that it will give Cersei trouble.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Warning:** This entire answer will contain spoilers from *A Dance With Dragons*.

There are several reasons why this would be a great move for Aegon. Tyrion has proven that he is a stout political strategist and would see these things.

**Independence**
Tyrion sees that Aegon will need to show his strength and will to his subordinates in order to win supporters to his cause.
Time and time again, supporters have left or been disillusioned of their leaders<sup>**1**</sup> due to spotting weakness.

Aegon will not have much support if the people of Westeros see him as a child whose lead by some old Griffon. He clearly needs to establish his dominance and prove his worthiness before people will flock to his cause.

**Foot-hold**
Strategically, this is a good move, as the details of the plan are for Aegon to grab a castle or two before anyone notices, thereby giving him a strong foot-hold and a gateway into Westeros; it worked for [Aegon the Conqueror](http://awoiaf.westeros.org:8080/index.php/Aegon_I_Targaryen)!

**Don't go to Dany, let her come to you**
As mentioned in the same chapter you quoted:

> Tyrion is convinced that Daenerys will fly to Aegon's side and immediately love him, as he is the last of her line, **and she is above all a "rescuer"**.<sup>[2](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_VI_(A_Dance_with_Dragons))</sup>

And not only that, but why go to your Auntie asking for help, when you are the rightful King and need to show your strength and leadership by making your own path?

**Don't make the same mistakes**
Daenerys is in a way trapped in Meereen. She is far, far away from Westeros and is surrounded by enemies - or at the very least, by strangers. It would not do for Aegon to be there; he will either:

- Help Dany win her fights, and then what?
- Lose with Dany

Those are not good options for Aegon, but rather distractions.

**Aegon** is the prize and he is the one whom it's all about (at least Tyrion says so):

> Tyrion had no sooner exhaled than Young Griff grabbed hold of his arm. “What do you mean? I am *everything*? What did you mean by that? Why am I everything?” 
> “Why,” said Tyrion, “if the stone men had taken Yandry or Griff or our lovely Lemore, we would have grieved for them and gone on. Lose *you*, and this whole enterprise is undone, and all those years of feverish plotting by the cheesemonger and the eunuch will have been for naught … isn’t that so?”
> <sup>*-A Song of Ice and Fire: A Dance With Dragons, Part One - Dreams and Dust (Tyrion).*</sup>

**What guarantee is there that she will help?**
Tyrion is afraid that Dany won't accept Aegon. He comes out of nowhere and lays claims to all the things she has been promised, worked hard and sacrificed so much for

**3**

---

<sup>**1.** Some examples of defectors</sup>

- Freys and Boltons defecting to Lannister side
- Blackfyre Rebellion 1
- Blackfyre Rebellion 2
- Secret workings of Prince Doran / Dorne

**2.** http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_VI_(A_Dance_with_Dragons)

**3.** From A *Dance With Dragons*:

> Now, how do you suppose this queen will react when you turn up with your begging bowl in hand and say, ‘Good morrow to you, Auntie. I am your nephew, Aegon, returned from the dead. I’ve been hiding on a poleboat all my life, but now I’ve washed the blue dye from my hair and I’d like a dragon, please … and oh, did I mention, my claim to the Iron Throne is stronger than your own?’ ”

Comment: good answer, your second citation is missing though?

Answer (score 8):

In addition to Mooz's answer, If I remember correctly, Tyrion said that Westeros is now the most vulnerable it'll ever be:

- An 8 year old is on the throne, with his crazy mother acting as Queen Regent
- Tywin is dead -> Lannisters aren't really a strong force now
- King of the North is dead
- Stannis is fighting Bolton on the North
- A bastard is Lord Commander of the Night's Watch
- Renly is dead

etc.

So, if Aegon chose to go to Dany for help, until the time they got back the Westeros, things might have changed; Dany is half a world away and Aegon didn't even know if she would be willing to work alongside with him, despite the common goal.

Comment: right and even if aegon fails his forces are strong enough to basically mess the rest of westeros up enough for dany to literally walk in and win.

Comment: Excellent additions. Never miss a thing you! +1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, which are excellent, I would also like to add that Tyrion may have wanted to return home. At this point in the story, he would presumably accompany Aegon and his crew on their journey to Westeros. And as long as his sister and the current Lannister/Tyrell regime was in place, he would be a dead man if he ever returned to Westeros by himself.

Comment: Yes, and give Cersei hell while he's at it!